# Magento Soap Interface, Invalid WSDL

Tags: api, magento, soap

I am having a problem where the soap interface to Magento (http://172.16.0.119/index.php/api/v2_soap?wsdl) is generating invalid wsdl.  When I try to generate a proxy using visual studio I get an error that there are several elements declared more than once in the document for example

> Source:     Line: 44 Column: 4   Validation Error: The global element
>   'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/:Array' has already been
>   declared

I thought that perhaps I had something corrupted in my magento install as I have several plugins and such running, so I done a fresh install of magneto 1.6.1 with no plugins or anything.  I still receive this error.  Has anybody else had this problem? How did you resolve it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a setting within the admin module that allows you to set the WS-I (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Services_Interoperability) Compliance flag to **True**. I was receiving a number of issues with VS2010 and the Magento API until I changed this flag.

It can be found in **System -> Configuration -> Services -> Magento Core API**

Hope this helps.

Comment: THANK YOU SOOOOOOO MUCH! I spend hours searching for this and found nothing!

Comment: No problems, glad I could help!